# Will any Pokemon appear in a horde?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

**Is there only certain Pokemon that will appear in a horde?** Or will all regular wild, except for legendary, appear in hordes? And if I run out of honey is there another way to encounter these types of battles more often?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only horde encounter certain Pokemon, in certain areas. Someone made a list of all the Pokemon you can horde encounter and where [here.](http://www.smogon.com/forums/threads/horde-battles-and-ev-yields.3490052/)

If you run out of honey you can use [sweet scent](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Sweet_Scent_%28move%29) to get horde battles.

Comment: The Zangoose&Seviper Horde is quite a special horde. If you want to catch the Zangoose, you'd better defeat the Sevipers *fast*.

Comment: @Nolonar actually catching the Zangoose (at least in Y) is mostly luck (and focusing on sevipers). Even if you OHKO the sevipers they'll only not defeat the Zangoose if they miss or only use weak attacks (wrap instead of bite). I think X gets more zangoose though

Comment: Yeah, in X you can find Zangooses fairly easy (not in horde), but seviper is a different story.

Comment: In X, you get 4 Zangoose/1 Seviper hordes and solo Zangoose. In Y, it's the other way around. If you want to catch the single one in the hordes, you need an attack that hits all and is strong enough to faint or severely damage the 4 and leave the one mainly safe. For X, Struggle Bug is well suited for this as it's non-effective against Poison, so Seviper resists it, but Zangoose doesn't. Fine-tune you (for example) Vivillon's level and Special attack to faint all Zangoose and have the Seviper survive. For Y, use Bulldoze, which is super-effective against Poison, but not against Normal.